# PHP MySQL and Server Efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, cron, server

I wanted to know how to do the below scenario without wasting the server resources.

There is a hardware devices that send files continuously to the server and my server need to record them into the db. (Only file's details)

My current strategy is to run a cronjob that will check through this folder and record them one by one for the details. If it exist then skip otherwise save into database. But think back in later day when a folder have like 1 million files. Is the scripts going to loop 1 by 1 and by then it wasn't efficient enough to do so.

How can I tweak this into an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can just restrict you loop with specific count like 10 files at a time or 100 files at a time.!

Or you create one strategy what ever file is processed put it into another folder. It will save your resource time. From processed files